# Remove password from password protected directory on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .htaccess, password-protection, plesk, .htpasswd

I have downloaded full directory from windows server... the directory was password protected directory... configured by Plesk Panel to prevent user access asp.net website without password.

I have now working with same code files on visual studio, but when running the solution on browser, the browser asked for Username & Password for the site.. although when I cancel, I'm still able to access the page.. but it asks for Username/Password on each page visit.

I have searched for .htaccess & .htpasswd file as mentioned on some forum to remove this.. but unfortunately it wasn't there in directory.

Not sure why this is asking for user id & password and how to remove it... With this kind of thing, I can not publish site to live server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is any resource referred from any other url which is stored on password protected folder of the server? If there are any such resource, remove them, or load them from your local system and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much.I was trying a lot to find this out and you have solved in min...Thanks again.